# Play framework: setting a java method return value to a javascript var

Tags: java, javascript, playframework

Is there's a way to get the value returned by a java controller method in javascript in the views ?

what I want to do is:

i'm in view showX rendered by controller method X.show()

i want to create an object y so $.post('@{Y.create()}')

now i need the id of the created object of type y to use it in the same view (showX).

is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sound like what you need (although your question is very vague), is to return JSON from your controller method.

Such as, in your controller, you can do

```
public static void myActionOne() {
    renderJSON(myObject);
}
```

And then you will call `myActionOne` from your javascript using `$.post`. I would also suggest looking at the Play `jsAction` tag if you are not already using it. This will return a JSON representation of the object. You can then take whatever information you need and call a second action in the same way.

Again, in the second action, I would suggest `jsAction`, as it makes passing parameters into your actions far easier.

**EDIT**:
Based on your edit, then all you need to do is in your controller method Y.create, do something like

```
public static void create() {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.save();
    Long id = obj.id;
    renderJSON(id);
}
```

Obviously your code to create your object will be different, but you get the idea. You can then just take the data from the JQuery post response, and access the id that has been returned, using standard javascript.

Comment: sorry if my question isn't clear enough but the problem is the controller isn't related to the view i want to get the value in. 
what I want to do is:
i'm in view showX rendered by controller method X.show()
i want to create an object y so $.post('@{Y.create()}')
now i need the id of the created object of type y.

Answer (score 1):

You question is too vague. But you probably will need of AJAX to get a value of this kind.

Take a look here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/ajax-135201.html

Comment: Well, I'm calling a controller method that creates an object (from a script using $.post() )and i want to get the id of the created object to pass it to another controller method.

Comment: I just forgot to say that the second method i want to call with the value returned from the first one is in a different controller class

Comment: Just do another AJAX call that access this other controller.